# How to prove AB is not equal to BC

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

[image]

IS there any way to prove AB is not equal to BC? the figure is drawn to scale. And this is a gre question.

Comment: If that's all we're given then the answer is no: it can't be proven $\;AB>BC\;$ since the given figure could be a square...

Comment: We cannot prove that $AB$ is not equal to $BC$, since they could be equal. but one can show that, given the information above, $AB$ does not **need** to be equal to $BC$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B could be on the Thales circle over AC, and AB need not be equal to BC.

One method to check whether AB : BC is the same proportion as CD : DA
could be to draw a line between B and D. If the line crosses the line
AC in the middle, the proportion is the same. Otherwise not.

Bye

See also: [Thales theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $\angle DAB$ need not be right.

Pun intended.

Comment: can you draw a pic for this ?

Comment: @mathphy In the GRE, you are only supposed to use the given information. Why don't you draw a diagram where $\angle DAB$ is not right, as in $90^\circ$.

Comment: from the condition , I got, ${AB}^2 +{BC}^2= 6\sqrt{2}$ then what?

Comment: What I think is I can chose different base and height the hypotenuse $6\sqrt{2}$. so they may not be equal. Am I right?

Comment: @mathphy Yes. we could have $AB = 1$ and $BC = \sqrt{71}$. This question is playing on your senses and making you think that $\angle DAB = 90^\circ$ which makes it a square. But that is not necessary.

Comment: And then the answer seems to be: no, it can't be proven that $\;AB>BC\;$ with the given info.